# how can i access the value of the drop down list which is getting populated using database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

i am facing a problem in asp.net, where i am using 2 drop down lists,

one is for state and other is for city.

and, i have 2 tables "state"(state_id(pk),state_name) and "city"(city_id(pk),city_name,state_id(fk))

i can populate the ddlState(which is my dropdown list for state) using the state table

the code for that is :

```
 dt = objGetCity.getState();

 ddlState.DataSource = dt;

 ddlState.DataTextField = dt.Columns["state_name"].ToString();
 ddlState.DataValueField = dt.Columns["state_id"].ToString();
 ddlState.DataBind();
```

also i can populate the drop down list for city i.e. ddlCity (on change event of the state drop down list)

the code for this is :

```
 protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int state_id = Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue.ToString());

        dt = objGetCity.getcity(state_id);

        ddlCity.Items.Add("Select City");

        ddlCity.Visible = true;

        ddlCity.DataSource = dt;

        ddlCity.DataValueField = dt.Columns["city_id"].ToString();
        ddlCity.DataTextField = dt.Columns["city_name"].ToString();
        ddlCity.DataBind();
    }
```

now the problem i noticed while debuging, for all the time, the "state_id=1" and thats why it's not showing me any other city from other state.what could be the solution?

Comment: make sure it is not due to postback !!

Comment: To extend Anands suggestion: Please show us your `Page_Load` and similar events. Strip them down to code that addresses your `DropDownList`s.

Answer (score 2):

make sure that you fill ddlState in page load with condition of not postback , i.e make sure that you've added this in the Page_Load Event

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{

dt = objGetCity.getState();

 ddlState.DataSource = dt;

 ddlState.DataTextField = dt.Columns["state_name"].ToString();
 ddlState.DataValueField = dt.Columns["state_id"].ToString();
 ddlState.DataBind();
}
```